# SSLSocketFactory ignore server certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I need to create a `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` that establish a TLS connection but ignores the validation of the server certificate. Not for HTTP protocol. I know this is not the right thing to do, but I NEED it. I don't want or like it.

I made an implementation that works but validate the server cert (as it supposes to be) implementation looks as following:

```
/**
     * Provide a quick method to construct a SSLSocketFactory which is a TCP socket using TLS/SSL
     * @param trustStore location of the trust store
     * @param keyStore location of the key store
     * @param trustStorePassword password to access the trust store
     * @param keyStorePassword password to access the key store
     * @return the SSLSocketFactory to create secure sockets with the provided certificates infrastructure
     * @exception java.lang.Exception in case of something wrong happens
     * */
    static public SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory ( final String trustStore, final String keyStore, final String trustStorePassword, final String keyStorePassword) throws Exception
    {

        // todo check if the CA needs or can use the password
        final FileInputStream trustStoreStream = new FileInputStream(trustStore);
        final FileInputStream keyStoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyStore);
        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        final KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        caKs.load(trustStoreStream, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
        tmf.init(caKs);

        trustStoreStream.close();

        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate us
        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(keyStoreStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
        kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        keyStoreStream.close();

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }
```

Comment: Define 'as it supposes to be'. The existing certificate validation system works well enough for most ordinary purposes. What's special about yours? And if you don't want it secure, why use SSL at all?

Comment: @EJP I don't want to I need to. I don't understand why I have to explain my motivation. In my work is needed. I know it's not right, and I would like to do it differently but I NEED (not want) to do it like this!

Comment: How to ignore server certificate validation is well explained across the web in every language that supports SSL and TLS. In fact, have a look at [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html). The authors provide exemplary code that avoids the checks (they are telling folks, *"don't do this"*).

Comment: Two other things... when you don't perform hostname validation you can switch to anonymous Diffie-Hellman for the same effect. Anonymous Diffie-Hellman avoids sending the server's certificate so it saves some time during channel setup. There is also a `eNULL` cipher that does not use encryption. `eNULL` provides the best throughput of all the cipher suites because it does not apply encryption :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to create a dummy `X509TrustManager` class that basically accepts all server certs without checking.

Then create an instance and pass it as the 2nd argument in your `SSLContext::init` call.

But seriously, this is a bad idea.  If you are not going to check the CERT, then using SSL is pointless or worse<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Here's my theory.  You have been told by your security folks that using MTTQ over an insecure channel is dangerous.  Or they have blocked port 1883. But you have a MTTQ / SSL server that you can't be bothered to get a proper CERT for.  So you are just trying to throw something together that "works".  Guess what.  If the people who told you to use SSL find out, they will [have your guts for garters!](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/guts-for-garters.html)  And if you are not doing this for this reason, then ... well ... what you are doing makes no sense.  Even a self-signed server CERT is better than this.  You just need to add it as a trusted cert in the client-side keystore.</sup>

Comment: You are right but it's not me who is doing it wrong. I have to connect to a partner Socket using self-sign certificates. But the partner is incapable to do it correctly. He deploys a server with wrong certs and he it's not even able to give me CA. I need to connect to fulfill a deadline regardless the partner doing.

Comment: Actually, you **are** doing it wrong.  You **don't** need him to give you the CA.  You just add his server CERT as a trusted CERT in your client keystore.   But if you deliver him (or your company) software that is ignoring CERTS and trusting everything, that is a faulty software,

Comment: Again, you don't know and do not need to know all. But anyhow, the server cert is wrong because is issued to a domain in which is not. Therefore, I want to ignore the CERT completely

Comment: Sorry ... but we did need to know this in order to give a **responsible** answer.